# How to listen for updates in mongodb with websockets

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io, mongodb-query, database

I'm trying to set up a notification system for my web app. Currently, I want to add an extra field to my mongo db, and have this update my front end in real time using socket.io

I know previously mongo had no functionality for listening to updates in its database - but has anything been recently released? Or is there another option to database triggers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Change Streams which is supported in many languages.

Since you are using socket.io you can see the node.js implementation

```
const collection = db.collection('inventory');
const changeStream = collection.watch();
changeStream.on('change', next => {
  // process next document
});
```

Here is the link: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/